# Is it possible to start/pause auto refreshing content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this script to auto refresh my content every 10 seconds.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#stats').load('stats.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
```

However, I need to add start/pause button to start and pause the refresh. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a general sense you can get a pause effect with any `setInterval()` by adding a flag:

```
var paused = false,
    auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
       if (paused) return false;
       $('#stats').load('stats.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000);

$("#idOfPauseButton").click(function() {
    paused = !paused;
    this.value = paused ? "Restart" : "Pause";
});
```

I find this method simpler than using `clearInterval()` to pause and `setInterval()` again to restart.

Obviously this assumes you use a single button to pause/restart:

```
<input id="idOfPauseButton" value="Pause" type="button">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/NWa56/

Comment: Using `clearInterval` wont make life easier. +1 for nice tricks

Comment: That is absolutely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

HTML

```
<button onclick="int=Stop();">Pause</button>
<button onclick="int=Start();">Start</button>
```

JS

```
var int = Start();

function Start() {
    // Start Loading the content
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function () {
        $('#stats').load('stats.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000);
    return auto_refresh;
}

function Stop() {
    // Stop loading the content
    // The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as 
    // the parameter for the clearInterval() method.
    return clearInterval(int);
}
```

Comment: Nice to see the _clearInterval()_ alternative, but this doesn't account for the user clicking "Start" repeatedly (without clicking "Pause").